# Prevent Safari (iPhone) to show an URL bar on form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, safari

I have found several javascript fixes to hide the Safari URL bar, great.

However it seems that form input fields tend to toggle it visible again if you've hidden it previously.. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

If it's not possible I guess I have to add an eventlistener that gives me a style hook on the URLs bar whereabouts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution

```
$('body')
    .on('touchstart', 'input', function(e) {
        e.target.focus();
        return false;
    })
    .on('focus', 'input', function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        return false;
    });
```

Address bar doesn't show at all with this code

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix..

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}, 500);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
```

stops the input behaviour..

Answer (score 0):

It took me a lot of time to figure out the solution.
You can try setting the body position to `fixed`.
For me it worked both in safari and chrome in iOS.

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.position = 'fixed';`

And when u don't need it anymore:

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.position = 'relative'`;

My use case: I have to show the addressbar when I make some div full screen and then go back to normal flow when its minimized.