# How to show the iOS Safari address bar with javascript?

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, scrolltop

I'm using jQuery to animate the scrollTop based on changes to the hash in the location. Works great.

The problem is, when I click "Home", I want it to scroll all the way to real top-- INCLUDING the address bar.

Apparently this is the opposite behavior of what most people want. So there are many questions out there about how to keep that pesky address bar hidden.

For my case, I want to be able to scroll (using JavaScript) to the top of the page. Right now when I try animating scrollTop to 0 or to -100 or to -500 it just puts me to the top of the content and the address bar stays hidden.

Comment: Are you working in objective-C or are you talking about a website you are designing... if it's objective-c this should work:  `[webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`

Comment: Thanks Albert-- no I'm working on the web.

Comment: Ah, sorry! Wish I could be of more use!

Comment: Apparently setting a form field to the current input reveals the URL bar again... you could scroll to top then try revealing it this way. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669779/prevent-safari-iphone-to-show-an-url-bar-on-form-input

Comment: Maybe loading a fake link? Or even doing something like appending a pound sign # to the end of the current URL might display the URL bar? Based on that thread?

Answer (score 2):

you could try setting `document.body.scrollTop=0`. This will show the address bar. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for me this works:

```
document.body.scrollTop = -1
```

...but the content is a bit shifted afterwards due to the momentum scrolling, so I usually use an short interval that sets the scrollTop to -1 until its at the right position.

I use this helper...

```
const showMobileUrlBar = () => {

  let i = 0
  const to = setInterval(() => {

    document.body.scrollTop = -1

    // clear timeout after 250 ms and reset scrollTop to 0
    if (i++ > 25) {
      clearInterval(to)
      document.body.scrollTop = 0
    }

  }, 10)

}
```

...which can be used in an onComplete callback when animating the scroll position, like this:

```
TweenMax.to(window, 0.5, {scrollTo: 0, onComplete: showMobileUrlBar})
```

Not the best solution but it works on iPad and iPhone.